# "unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'GreaterThan'" issure

Tags: python

I have this issue:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-88-03e362e106e6> in <module>
     12               g : 9.81,
     13               l : 2.0,
---> 14               f: force(t)}
     15 
     16 # Create a function from the equations of motion

<ipython-input-86-565059232bb5> in force(t)
      6 
      7 # return a bang-bang command
----> 8     return fmax * ((t > 0.25) - 2 * (t >= 1.25) + (t >= 2.25))

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'GreaterThan'"
```

I tried to solve it but I can't. Can someone help me ?

from this code:

```
def force(t):
  # set the maximum force output
  
  fmax = 10
  
# return a bang-bang command
  return fmax * ((t > 0.25) - 2 * (t >= 1.25) + (t >= 2.25))


# Define the states and state vector
w1, w2, w3, w4 = sympy.symbols('w1 w2 w3 w4', cls=sympy.Function)
w = [w1(t), w2(t), w3(t), w4(t)]

# Set up the state definitions and parameter substitution
sub_params = {x : w1(t),
            theta : w2(t), 
            x_dot : w3(t),
            theta_dot : w4(t), 
            mt : 10.0,
            m : 1.0,
            g : 9.81, 
            l : 2.0, 
            f: force(t)}

# Create a function from the equations of motion
# Here, we substitude the states and parameters as appropriate prior to the lamdification
eq_of_motion = sympy.lambdify((t, w), lrhs.subs(sub_params))
```

Comment: and what is `t` ?

Comment: it is the time that evolved

Comment: it seems being of type `GreaterThan` the error is pretty explicit. What do you expect when being used with numbers ?

Comment: `t = sympy.GreaterThan` or `t = returns_sympyGreaterThan()` exists somewhere in your code